# How to upload Node modules to Nexus private repository

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nexus

I am running private nexus `npm` repo for my Org, all the packages are installed on my local machine through the internet and I want to keep my all the packages on my NPM private repo on Nexus, I am able to upload all the node modules using `npm` publish command and after the upload I am tried to install the dependency on my machine.

Throwing error: Unable to download the packages using `npm install` command.
We are using angular with NPM, and I am facing a dependency error.

Is there any way to upload and download the packages on nexus private repo?

I have listed the `node_modules` packages name and tried `npm` publish command to upload all the packages to the server

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @babel/parser@7.5.0
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-nne9/IiQ/hzIhY6pdDnbBtz7DjPTKrY00P/zvPSm5pOFkl6xuGrGnXn/VtTNNfNtAfZ9/
1RtehkszU9qcTii0Q== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-
    nne9/IiQ/hzIhY6pdDnbBtz7DjPTKrY00P/zvPSm5pOFkl6xuGrGnXn/VtTNNfNtAfZ9/
1RtehkszU9qcTii0Q== but got sha512-
        K7DzI/3tkHzKWDYntJSgSY26J9VHfMp4K45WPKuRzqeIFbV9LnaAkA/
        LeQ7lrJdVMl4mbUQKg4KuK+JlJP12Bg==. (2753 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the error but am answering generally, as I suspect I can define your case and the other cases I go over may be helpful to others who are not in your situation but come across this question.

The answer really depends where the dependancies are/are defined.

In the package.json, the dependencies can be absolute URLs, which causes the npm client to bypass NXRM and download the artifacts directly.  More about that [here](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465048-Why-does-npm-client-need-access-to-URLs-other-than-my-private-registry-).  If these are causing your error, I suspect nothing can be done short term on the NXRM side.  There is a (not public) ticket in our backlog to investigate if we can ease this case as well but in this case you'd be left with making sure everything works or downloading them from there and putting them into your hosted.

The way NXRM is designed to work is all the dependancies are accessable through NXRM.  So the expectation is either they're in your hosted repository as aforementioned or in some public proxy repository.

If the former, I'd make sure they're all there (using the error as a starting place).
If the latter, then rather than download and push them all, you can create a proxy of the public repository(s) and then make an npm group to be the single source to call from.  If you have 3 public repos with dependancies you can put them (and your hosted) all in that group and just use that.  More about groups [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-GroupingnpmRegistries) in our general npm documentation.